# Stop the AVAudioPlayer when the App enters Background

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I would like to stop an infinite Background Music when the app is not active any more in my `GameViewController`. I found a way to make this in Objective-C but I need it in Swift. I tried working with the `viewDidUnload` but this did not work at all.

This is how I implemented my bgMusic.

```
var bgMusic:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

var bgMusicURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bgMusic", withExtension: "wav")!
bgMusic = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL, error: nil)
bgMusic.numberOfLoops = -1
bgMusic.prepareToPlay()
bgMusic.play()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the AppDelegate, there is a Method for this case.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
```

Comment: how do I connect the AppDelegate to my `GameViewController`

Comment: Is it the rootView controller? Then simply `window?.rootViewController`.

Comment: It is the normal created View Controller when starting a sprite kit game in xcode.

Comment: Ok then it is the root view controller so you can use the explained method above.

Comment: Ok I get that, but I can only pause the music in the view controller but there is no method called that allows me to stop the music ( sorry I am really new to coding )

Comment: Declare the variable outside of View didLoad then you can access it from app delegate over the rootviewcontroller or simply write an method which stops the music :)

Comment: Ok finally I got that, Thanks!!